# Why does .idq return no results?

Tags: windows, iis, indexing-service

I have an extremely old web app that I need to move to a new server. It uses Internet Data Query files for search with a indexing service catalog.

After going through some struggles getting the idq files to be handled correctly in IIS, it now works however it always returns zero results from my catalog.

We have another site on the server which was migrated last year that I have been using as a working example of setting up the IDQ/HTX search. I am even able to go into the site I am trying to migrate and point it to the other sites catalog and it will work.

I am wondering if something special needs to be done when setting up the indexing service catalog to allow it to be consumed in IDQ? I have a small asp utility that I can give a catalog name and search param to and it will return results. So I know the results are being indexed in the catalog. They just aren't coming through when viewing the IDQ page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2009/11/20/how-to-index-iis-7-0-web-sites-in-windows-server-2008-by-indexing-service.aspx

Looks like it was because of some changes in Windows Server 2008.